# How to delete discovered bluetooth devices on ios 7?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, bluetooth

I use BeeTee project for discover nearby bluetooth devices. Everything is good, but if it discovered a device its store this somewhere, and i cant find it again. If the device doesnt send bluetooth signal the bluetooth manager write this in log: BTM: lost device "device_name" device_address

How can i delete discovered devices?

Answer (score 1):

They are stored in a dictionary:

```
@property (retain, nonatomic) NSMutableDictionary *currentAvailableDevices;
```

If you want to delete one of them, you can call the the delegate method

```
- (void)removeBluetoothDevice:(BluetoothDevice *)bluetoothDevice
{
    [self.currentAvailableDevices removeObjectForKey:bluetoothDevice.address];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

But are you sure that this approach makes sense?

Comment: By the way, I am working on an update for BeeTee. Maybe this is helpful for you.